# Running a CUFFT rountine in Nvidia-Docker

Tags: python, linux, docker, cuda, nvidia-docker

i'm new to Docker, especially to Nvidia-Docker. I'm trying to wrap my code into docker container and run it on some hosts. But apparently something goes wrong and i'm not able to run my code in docker. I have installed Nvidia-docker and Dockerfile is taken from [here](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/container-images/cuda/blob/master/dist/ubuntu16.04/9.1/devel/Dockerfile). Here is my full docker code

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:9.1-runtime-ubuntu16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        cuda-command-line-tools-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
        cuda-libraries-dev-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
        cuda-minimal-build-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
&& \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs

FROM python:3.7-slim
RUN pip install numpy
RUN apt update && \
    apt-get -y install gcc && \
    apt-get -y install g++
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility
ADD helmsolver /helmsolver
CMD dpkg -l | grep -i cuda
CMD cd helmsolver && bash tests.sh
```

And a bash script code where cudahelmf and cudahelmd are previously compiled by

```
nvcc helm3dcudafnd.cu -o cudahelm -I/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc/ -lcufft -lcufftw -D DOUBLE
```

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir helmholtz
cd helmholtz
        mkdir build
        mkdir workdir
        mkdir src
        mkdir scripts
        ls
        cp ../cudahelmf ./build
        cp ../cudahelmd ./build
        cp ../tmp.py ./scripts/
        cd workdir
        python3 ../scripts/script1.py 21 21 1
        ../build/cudahelmd config.cfg >> results_double.txt
        ../build/cudahelmf config.cfg >> results_float.txt
```

To build and run docker i use

```
nvidia-docker build -t helm .
nvidia-docker run --rm -ti helm
```

And after running i have error

```
../build/cudahelmd: error while loading shared libraries: libcufft.so.9.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What am i doing wrong? Does it happens because of the -lcufft compile option and docker doesn't know where to get it? And docker doesn't have /usr/local/cuda/ directory after installation. It seems strange due to cuda-libraries-dev include cufft library and installations ends successfully.

Here is nvcc version on my computer where code was compiled and previously tested.

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

And nvidia-docker version

```
Docker version 19.03.3, build a872fc2f86
```

P.S. Maybe there is an option to compile code in docker?

Comment: @RobertCrovella It didn't help

Comment: are there any `libcufft...` files in your `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` directory in the container? Which are they?

Comment: @RobertCrovella there is no such directory as i mentioned before

Comment: What happens if you  just start with `FROM nvidia/cuda:9.1-runtime-ubuntu16.04` and don't install the next 3 cuda packages you have in your dockerfile?  When I do that  I have a directory /usr/local/cuda/lib64 with the needed cufft libraries in it.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Nothing happens, no new directories, especially cuda. Can you show your full Dockerfile?

Comment: When I do this: `docker run  --runtime=nvidia --rm  -it nvidia/cuda:9.1-runtime-ubuntu16.04` I get a container that has the `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` directory in it, with the appropriate libcufft... files.  Do you?

Comment: you can compile code in a docker container.  Use one of the cuda `devel` tags.  And, FWIW, you could compile your code against `-lcufft_static` to statically link to cufft and avoid this particular issue.  But there is something strange about your container setup

Comment: @RobertCrovella Well, your docker worked well and i was able to get `/usr/local/cuda/lib64/` directory, thus something in my docker call is wrong

Answer (score 2):

the problem is you are running a multistage dockerfile without `COPY` from one to another , therefore you will be end only with the standalone `python3` container which has nothing from `nvidia` container, so you need to copy the required files like this in `python` container:

```
COPY --from=0 SOURCE DEST
```

Comment: Thanks, i got it but still can't run my code. If i got it right, `COPY` must be after the `FROM` command? So, i do `FROM` and `COPY` in python and CUDA sections?

Comment: The copy should only be in python section and you need also to set the env also in python section

Comment: Thank you, @LinPy! I was able to run python and cuda at the same time, but a new problem appeared. Now cuda throws the 35 error code `cudaErrorInsufficientDriver`. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: please consider o open a new post with all of the current setup .... this post should be done since it resolve the main problem in the question